# How to format message with argument names instead of numbers?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have something like:

```
String text = "The user {0} has email address {1}."
// params = { "Robert", "myemailaddr@gmail.com" }
String msg = MessageFormat.format(text, params);
```

This isn't great for me, because sometimes my translators are not sure what goes in the {0} and {1}, also it would be nice to be able to reword the messages without worrying about the order of the args.

I'd like to replace the arguments with readable names instead of numbers.  Something like this:

```
String text = "The user {USERNAME} has email address {EMAILADDRESS}."
// Map map = new HashMap( ... [USERNAME="Robert", EMAILADDRESS="myemailaddr@gmail.com"]
String msg = MessageFormat.format(text, map);
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!
rob

Comment: Commons Lang has StrSubstitutor

Comment: I can be wrong, but looks like [JTPL](http://jtpl.sourceforge.net/) can help you out.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2286648/435605

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `MapFormat` for this. Find out the details here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/AtextformatsimilartoMessageFormatbutusingstringratherthannumerickeys.htm

```
String text = "The user {name} has email address {email}.";
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("name", "Robert");
map.put("email", "rhume55@gmail.com");

System.out.println("1st : " + MapFormat.format(text, map));
```

OUTPUT:

> 1st : The user Robert has email address rhume55@gmail.com.

Answer (score 24):

See [StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from `org.apache.commons.lang3`:

```
Map valuesMap = HashMap();
valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.";
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);

// resolvedString: "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
```

Comment: any idea how solve this if for example target is optional and then you want to have empty string instead of ${target}, to set an empty string in the map the only way ?

Comment: @poyger Did not try this, but you could probably override `Map` to return `""` instead of `null` for keys that are not mapped.

Comment: as of today, 2018-02, this class has been moved to commons-text: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StrSubstitutor.html

Comment: StrSubstitutor is now deprecated. You should use org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor from commons-text.

Answer (score 10):

Easy to make one yourself. This is what I use (the `main()` function is just for test code):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringTemplate {
    final private String template;
    final private Matcher m;
    static final private Pattern keyPattern = 
        Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*)\\}");
    private boolean blanknull=false;

    public StringTemplate(String template) { 
        this.template=template;
        this.m = keyPattern.matcher(template);
    }

    /**
     * @param map substitution map
     * @return substituted string
     */
    public String substitute(Map<String, ? extends Object> map)
    {
        this.m.reset();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (this.m.find())
        {
            String k0 = this.m.group();
            String k = this.m.group(1);
            Object vobj = map.get(k);
            String v = (vobj == null) 
                ? (this.blanknull ? "" : k0)
                : vobj.toString();
            this.m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(v));
        }
        this.m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();       
    }

    public StringTemplate setBlankNull()
    {
        this.blanknull=true;
        return this;
    }

    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringTemplate t1 = new StringTemplate("${this} is a ${test} of the ${foo} bar=${bar} ${emergency.broadcasting.system}");
        t1.setBlankNull();
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put("this", "*This*");
        m.put("test", "*TEST*");
        m.put("foo", "$$$aaa\\\\111");
        m.put("emergency.broadcasting.system", "EBS");
        System.out.println(t1.substitute(m));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is closely related to: [How to replace a set of tokens in a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959731/how-to-replace-a-set-of-tokens-in-a-java-string)
You could use [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or another template library.  But there will be some pain because Java does not have any kind of Map literals.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer comes a little late, but if you still need this functionality, without the need to download a full-fledged template engine you can take a look at [aleph-formatter](https://github.com/nomemory/aleph-formatter) (I am one of the authors):

```
Student student = new Student("Andrei", 30, "Male");

String studStr = template("#{id}\tName: #{st.getName}, Age: #{st.getAge}, Gender: #{st.getGender}")
                    .arg("id", 10)
                    .arg("st", student)
                    .format();
System.out.println(studStr);
```

Or you can chain the arguments:

```
String result = template("#{x} + #{y} = #{z}")
                    .args("x", 5, "y", 10, "z", 15)
                    .format();
System.out.println(result);

// Output: "5 + 10 = 15"
```

Internally it works using a StringBuilder creating the result by "parsing" the expression, no string concatenation, regex/replace is performed.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final Pattern REPLACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\x24\\x7B([a-zA-Z][\\w\\x2E].*?)\\x7D");

/**
 * Check for unresolved environment
 *
 * @param str
 * @return origin if all substitutions resolved
 */
public static String checkReplacement(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = REPLACE_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        throw LOG.getIllegalArgumentException("Environment variable '" + matcher.group(1) + "' is not defined");
    }
    return str;
}

// replace in str ${key} to value
public static String resolveReplacement(String str, Map<String, String> replacements) {
    Matcher matcher = REPLACE_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String value = replacements.get(matcher.group(1));
        if (value != null) {
            str = matcher.replaceFirst(replaceWindowsSlash(value));
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

But you loose all format options (like ##.#)

Answer (score 0):

If use of a map is not a requirement, then you can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String username = "rtm";
String emailaddress = "noone@nowhere.com";
String text = STR."The user \{username} has email address \{emailaddress}."
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.
For example, string concatenation or interpolation makes SQL injection attacks possible:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = '" + name + "'";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

but this variant (from JEP 430) prevents SQL injection:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DB."SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = \{name}";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```