# Adding Java variable to xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is it possible to add a defined Java String variable to an xpath-expression? Here is some code to make it clear:

```
String newUser = "NewUser123";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[normalize-space(text())=**newUser**]/a")).click();
```

The xpath should work with the variable newUser, but I don´t know how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Including variables within strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643610/java-including-variables-within-strings)

Comment: Why the down votes? Its a valid question!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, when you choose Java as your programming language while working with selenium, you can perform all things that are logically possible in Java.

Take your example, xpath is a function which takes string arguments. So Like in Java we concatenate multiple strings using `+`. you can do the same thing here.

```
String newUser = "NewUser123";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[normalize-space(text())='"+newUser+"']/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Xpath` with variable and space

```
String CasesCount = Utility.WebDriverHelper.Wdriver.findElement
(By.xpath("//button[text()=' "+tabname+"']/span")).getText();
```

Remove this kind of special braces `()` in text

```
CasesCount  = CasesCount.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)","");
```

Answer (score 2):

In similar situations I will extract the lookup to a constant in the class, and use the *String.format* utility to insert the variable(s) where I need it. Note the use of **%s** in the example constant *USER_XPATH* below.

I think this is better for readability and maintenance than the inline concatenation option, but both will achieve the goal.

```
/** Format string for the ### xpath lookup.*/
private static final String USER_XPATH ="//td[normalize-space(text())=%s]/a";
```

Then you can use String.format to insert the variable you want:

```
 private void myMethod() {
      String newUser = "NewUser123";
      String fullXpath = String.format(USER_XPATH, newUser);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(fullXpath)).click();
    }
```

Comment: This is nice except that `%s` needs to be included between quotes (either single or double). Otherwise, it does not work. I mean it should be `private static final  USER_XPATH ="//td[normalize-space(text())='%s']/a";`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
String newUser = "NewUser123";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[normalize-space(text())=" + newUser + "]/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if its a number in any loop table it can be written like

String sCol = "1";

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/article/div/table/tbody/tr["+sRow+"]/td["+sCol+"]")).getText();

Answer (score -1):

Treat the xpath like any other string concatenation or interpolation you would do in Java