# Write array to HTML file in Java

Tags: java, html, arrays

I would like to write my array of objects to an HTML file in a loop. The HTML tags are correct as the table that I want is properly made. However, "menu.ArrObj[i].getName" is literally printed. I would like some help as to how the actual array is to be printed.

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\drivers\\A.html", true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(f);
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
 {
     bw.write("</tr><tr><td>menu.ArrObj[i].getName()</td> <td> align=\"right\">menu.ArrObj[i].getConcept() </td> <td align=\"right\"
```

Comment: What programming language is that? Is it Java?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20use%20variable%20in%20a%20string

Comment: It's Java language

Comment: Of course the literal value is printed, as it's a part of the write string and not used as a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Including variables within strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643610/java-including-variables-within-strings)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you just want to replace the `BufferedWriter` write line with:

```
 bw.write("</tr><tr><td>" + menu.ArrObj[i].getName() + "</td> <td> align=\"right\">" + menu.ArrObj[i].getConcept() + "</td> <td align=\"right\" ...)
```

Comment: I'm changing it to that to see if it solves my issue

Comment: @RaghavKapur that sounds like an unrelated error. Do you know when `NullPointerException`s typically occur? Examine `menu.ArrObj` to see which of its elements are `null`