# How to click on a button using button's label text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can somebody please help me on the following?

I want to click on a button who has the text "Resume Scanning".
In the below script. Instead of the hard coding (Resume Scanning), how can I pass the value from property file?

`driver.findElement(by.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Resume Scanning')]"));`

Thanks,
Kannan C

Answer (score 2):

try as follows:

```
String label = "Resume Scanning";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'" + label + "')]"));
```

Or using `String.format`:

```
String string = String.format("//button[contains(.,'%s')]", label);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(string));
```

Reference:

1. [Java - Including variables within strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643610/java-including-variables-within-strings)

Comment: I used this one String label = "Resume Scanning";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'" + label + "')]"));

Answer (score 0):

You can use following java code to read from properties file

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("location of properties file");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(in);
String buttonText=prop.getProperty(propertyName);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[contains(text(),'"+buttonText+"')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property file to read the text value. Here is an example:

```
inputParams.properties
----------------------
buttonLabel=Resume Scanning
```

Use the below sample code to read data from the property file:

```
FileReader reader=new FileReader("inputParams.properties");  
Properties p=new Properties();  
p.load(reader);  
System.out.println(p.getProperty("buttonLabel"));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Add Strategy')]")

By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Submit')]")

Comment: It may be helpful to provide some additional details, that explain what this code is doing, and how exactly this addresses the OP's question.

Comment: Its is html base xpath finder when driver find any button which text is same with define text it will get access.