# How to pass variable into SQL string

Tags: java, apache-spark, string-interpolation

I have one spark sql query which is accepting value as long.

```
Dataset getQuery = spark.sql("select * from trafficdata where message_time between 1486036800000 and 1486108800000 ")
```

i want this time to be as variables like

```
Long val1 = 1486036800000
Long val2 = 1486108800000
Dataset getQuery = spark.sql("select * from trafficdata where message_time between $val1 and $val2 ")
```

i tried with `$val1` but its not working. Could anyone suggest, how to do that in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Including variables within strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643610/java-including-variables-within-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should write the query as

```
"select * from trafficdata where message_time between '" + val1 + "' and '" + val2 + "'"
```

Comment: sql injection alert

Comment: SQL Injection: meaning this answer is only good for demonstration or your personal app not accessible over the public web - otherwise code is vulnerable to the most novice hacker.

Answer (score -1):

Try it out like this:

```
getQuery = spark.sql(String.format("select * from trafficdata where message_time between %d and %d ", val1, val2));
```