# What am I getting wrong with this Java statement sequence followed by variable inputs?

Tags: java

"Write a single statement that will print the message "first is " followed by the value of first, and then a space, followed by "second = ", followed by the value of second. Print everything on one line and go to a new line after printing. Assume that first has already been declared as a double and that second has been declared as an int. Assume also that the variables have already been given values."

what I have so far is..

```
double first = 1;
int second = 3;
System.out.println("first is 1 second = 3" + "\n");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Including variables within strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643610/java-including-variables-within-strings)

Comment: try something like: "first is "+first ... in your print statement.

Comment: Use `+` to seperate strings and values: `System.out.println("first is " + first +" second = " + second + "\n");`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't work. I'm thinking the problem may be with the assignment and declaring of the variables

Comment: Did what you had before work?

Answer (score 0):

Use + operator for contacting the variable.
`double first = 1;
int second = 3;
System.out.println("first is "+first+ " second = " +second+"\n");`