# How to have placeholder for variable value in Java Text Block?

Tags: java, java-14, java-text-blocks

How can I put a *variable* into Java [Text Block](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378)?

Like this:

```
"""
{
    "someKey": "someValue",
    "date": "${LocalDate.now()}",

}
"""
```

Comment: Its a representation of a `String` after all. At least for now without further detail over "why not try using an existing construct like `String.format`" , the question would stand as an exact duplicate. Leaving the rest for the community to decide.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Java - Including variables within strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643610/java-including-variables-within-strings)

Comment: I thought more about how to write java code inside the text block, `String.format` is more like a work around with which sadly I hadn't come up with...

Comment: @DennisGlot `String::format` is not a _workaround_, it is the normal way of doing string interpolation in Java.  (With text blocks, an instance version was also added, so you can say `"...".formatted(...)` if you prefer chaining.)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `%s` as a *placeholder* in text blocks:

```
String str = """
{
    "someKey": "someValue",
    "date": %s,
}
"""
```

and replace it using [format()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) method.

```
String.format(str, LocalDate.now());
```

---

From [JEP 378 docs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378):

> A cleaner alternative is to use String::replace or String::format, as follows:

```
String code = """
          public void print($type o) {
              System.out.println(Objects.toString(o));
          }
          """.replace("$type", type);

String code = String.format("""
          public void print(%s o) {
              System.out.println(Objects.toString(o));
          }
          """, type);
```

> Another alternative involves the introduction of a new instance method, String::formatted, which could be used as follows:

```
String source = """
            public void print(%s object) {
                System.out.println(Objects.toString(object));
            }
            """.formatted(type);
```

---

### NOTE

Despite that in the Java version 13 the `formatted()` method was marked as [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)), since **Java version 15** [`formatted(Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) method is officially part of the Java language, same as the Text Blocks feature itself.

Comment: Could you explain, why is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643610/java-including-variables-within-strings?

Comment: @Naman Because that question is about conventional string syntax, while this question is specifically about text blocks.

Comment: @BasilBourque The [JEP-355](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355) reads - *"It is not a goal to define a new reference type, distinct from java.lang.String, for the strings expressed by any new construct."* or to read the other way round, *"A text block is a **multi-line string** literal that avoids the need for most escape sequences, automatically formats the string in a predictable way, and gives the developer control over format when desired'.* (formatted by me). Anyway, leaving further for the community to decide for the clash of thoughts added to a lack of interest in the JEP.

Comment: `String.formatted` is not "really" deprecated. In fact, it is a new method (since Java 13). It is deprecated only because it is related to text blocks, which are a preview feature. But if you use text blocks, you can as well use this method.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...) it's safe to use it now

Comment: Regarding the deprecation: [“However, the deprecation-based approach was eventually dropped because it was confusing to see an API element introduced in the same Java SE release as it was deprecated, that is, to see @since 13 and @Deprecated(forRemoval=true, since="13") on the same API element.”](https://openjdk.org/jeps/12#:~:text=However%2C%20the%20deprecation,on%20the%20same%20API%20element.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String name = "Joan";
String info = STR."My name is \{name}";
assert info.equals("My name is Joan");   // true
```

It also supports Java's multi-line text blocks:

```java
String title = "My Web Page";
String text  = "Hello, world";
String html = STR."""
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>\{title}</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <p>\{text}</p>
          </body>
        </html>
        """;
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.
For example, here is a template processor that returns not strings but, rather, instances of JSONObject:

```java
var JSON = StringTemplate.Processor.of(
        (StringTemplate st) -> new JSONObject(st.interpolate())
    );

String name    = "Joan Smith";
String phone   = "555-123-4567";
String address = "1 Maple Drive, Anytown";
JSONObject doc = JSON."""
    {
        "name":    "\{name}",
        "phone":   "\{phone}",
        "address": "\{address}"
    };
    """;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example single-line use:

```java
String name = "Joan";
String info = STR."My name is \{name}";
assert info.equals("My name is Joan");   // true
```

It also supports Java's multi-line text blocks:

```java
String title = "My Web Page";
String text  = "Hello, world";
String html = STR."""
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>\{title}</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <p>\{text}</p>
          </body>
        </html>
        """;
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.
For example, string concatenation or interpolation makes SQL injection attacks possible:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = '" + name + "'";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

but this variant (from JEP 430) prevents SQL injection:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DB."SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = \{name}";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

and you could do something similar to create an HTML data structure, via a string template that quotes HTML entities.