# Pattern of string in java

Tags: java

I need to print out formulas like `"A{i}+B{i}+C{i}"` for some i so it would look like `A0+B0+C0` (for example). Is there any easy way to do it without regex?

I tried making regex but it's a bit inconvenient for this expression.

Comment: See also [_How to including variables within strings?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9643610/230513)

Comment: [*String Templates in Java 21*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-21-string-templates) and https://openjdk.org/jeps/430

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the String format to get a formatted output for some `i` as below (*Ordinary indexing*):

```
String.format("A%d+B%d+C%d", i, i, i)
```

But this can further shortened by using *Relative indexing* (argument from the previous format specifier is re-used)

```
String.format("A%d+B%<d+C%<d", i)
```

or *Explicit Indexing* (explicitly specifying the argument index to be used)

```
String.format("A%1$d+B%1$d+C%1$d", i)
```

Refer [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more information

Comment: Feels like a cleaner take on this is `String.format("A%d+B%<d+C%<d", i)`. `<` is format-ese for 'previous argument'. Avoids having to repeat `i` 3 times. Starting with JDK.. 23 probably, `STR."A\{i}+B\{i}+C\{i}"` will do it.